# Get type library file path from ITypeLib*

Tags: windows, visual-c++, reflection, com, typelib

I have an [`ITypeLib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221549.aspx)* that may or may not have been loaded from a file via [`LoadTypeLib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027.aspx). Is there a way to get the typelib file path from the [`ITypeLib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221549.aspx)*? Perhaps there's another interface I could use?

So far, I have determined that the [`TLIBATTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221376.aspx) returned from [`ITypeLib::GetLibAttr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221641.aspx) has a field [`TLIBATTR::wLibFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221376.aspx) that includes a bit [`LIBFLAGS::LIBFLAG_FHASDISKIMAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221149.aspx) when it is loaded via [`LoadTypeLib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027.aspx).

The [`TLIBATTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221376.aspx) also has a field [`TLIBATTR::guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221376.aspx) with which I can call [`QueryPathOfRegTypeLib`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221436.aspx), but that only works if the type library is registered. In my use case, the type library may or may not be registered.

Comment: No.  You've got the {guid} of the library, you might find it back in the registry if you're lucky.  HKLM\Software\Classes\Typelib key, beware the redirector.

Comment: In this case, the type library may be loaded without being registered. I just updated the question accordingly.

Comment: You're pretty hosed, then.  The typelib may not even exist on disk (could be from a resource, for example, or could be built in-memory on the fly).

Comment: The `LIBFLAG_FHASDISKIMAGE` that I mention in my post indicates that it's not built in-memory or from a resource. What I'm hoping for is that the underlying object implements some COM interface when loaded from a file. It would have to be a COM interface that I'm not familiar with. But yes, so far, hosed.